# VScode javadoc generation shortcut like Intellij

Tags: visual-studio-code, javadoc

Is there a way to generate the javadoc for a method by typing "/**" in VSCode just like in Intellij?
Intellij automatically writes annotations like parameter and return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, and it should be working for you (if it's not, then you're likely encountering a bug).

Here's the feature request issue ticket that requested that this feature be added:
https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/228.

Here's the Pull Request that implemented it:
https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls/pull/744.

Here's a bug report reporting that it stopped working that got resolved as fixed:
https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/811.

If it's not working for you, read through those threads and see if your issue is related to the Intellicode extension. If not, revive that third link I sent with details to reproduce your issue and logs.

As clarified in the comments, the issue was that the asker had two Java language server extensions installed. After uninstalling one of them ([`georgewfraser.vscode-javac`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=georgewfraser.vscode-javac)), their issue was resolved.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! The issue was not the intelliJ extensions, it was (I believe) the fact that I had 2 different Java language servers installed. Deinstalled "Java Language Support" from George Fraser, cleaned Java Language Server Workspace just to be sure and now it works.